# Sculpting Issue: Mesh disappears into another one

Tags: mesh, modifiers, sculpting, subdivision-surface, sculpt

[image: My Donut in Sculpting]

I was doing the Andrew Price tutorial (doughnut) and i am stuck in the sculpting phase. I was doing just fine but I think I messed up in the modifier section of the icing. For some reason, when I get to sculpting the icing (with the inflate brush), the icing just disappears into the donut. I donnt know what I did but I do know I tried undoing it (Ctrl+Z) and it did not work, just as Andrew Price said it would. The icing seems to disappear into the donut whenever im in SCULPTING. The dribbles peak out the donut but that is it, the rest of the icing is somehow gone. Any help is appreciated guys. Ill leave the link for the video here if its of any help. Thanks!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OTX3ZdYvEA

Comment: Please edit your post and add a specific title that describes your question clearly.

Answer (score 1):

In Sculpt Mode click *Sculpt* (to the right of where *Sculpt Mode* is shown) and now > "Show All".

For some reason, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> doesn't unhide properly between edit-mode and sculpt-mode for me. So if I hide vertices in edit-mode and switch back to sculpt mode, the connecting faces are gone. Going back to edit-mode, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> reveals the hidden vertices in edit-mode, but they are gone again when I switch back to sculpt-mode. Only in sculpt-mode I can *Show All* to un-hide those vertices again.